# Django-Simple-Friends all users not connected as friends

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm tyring to create a list of users who could be invited with Django-Simple-Friends

I would like the list to include all active users minus the logged in user and all the logged in user's friends.

I have a query that works to pull all the active users minus the logged in users but am not sure how to exclude the "friends"

Here's the query I'm using for all active users minus logged in user:

```
invite_user_list = User.objects.filter(~Q(id=request.user.id), is_active=True)
```

Any thoughts how I can remove the connected friends from the list?

I appreciate the time and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters):

```
invite_user_list = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(friendship__friends__user=request.user)
```

Comment: This query would work to provide a list of all users minus the logged in user but do you know how can I expand it to also exclude all connected "friends" of that user?

Comment: It does that. Notice that it's chaining two .exclude calls; the second one excludes connected friends.

Comment: Worked Perfect! I really appreciate it. (I fairly new to Stackoverflow and didn't notice you could scroll over on the code so I didn't see the 2nd .exclude)